# I want to make a button enabled only at specific time. How to do it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
        <div className='external-btn-cont'>
            <button className='external-score-btn' onClick={SENDSCORE}>Submit</button>
        </div>
```

How to do it?

Comment: what is that specific time?

Comment: I am fetching it from the DB. It is dynamic

Comment: So... you want to enable the button when the data is available? You should add the code for that to your question. [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Comment: create a state initially as `false` and as soon as the data comes then make that state to `true` and based on that state render your button.

Comment: I have created a state but how do I implement the other part?

Comment: No I want to enable it let say when it is 10:30pm on 2 march. Its just an example

Comment: You realise that anyone with access to the dev tools can simply override that?

Comment: that not an issue its a personal project of mine

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Date.now()` to get access to the [current time since Epoch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now). If you are unfamiliar the time since Epoch it is the anount of milliseconds that has passed since January 1, 1970, UTC.

We can use `Date.getTime()` to [convert your date to Epoch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime). Now we can compare these 2 times to see if the current day is correct

then we can implent the following kind of code

```
function Button(props){
    const [buttonEnabled, setButtonEnabled] = useState(false)

    useEffect(()=>{
        let currentTime = Date.now()
        let requiredTime = Date.getTime(YOURDATEHERE)
        if( currentTime == requiredTime){
            setButtonEnabled(true)
        }else{
            setButtonEnabled(false)
        }
    },[])

    return(
        {buttonEnabled == true:
        <div>
            <button>Im A Button</button>
        </div>
        ?
        <div>
            I am not enabled
        </div>
        }
    )
}
```

Ideally the above should create a button that is only shown at the exact millisecond that you require from when it is rendered. Obviously you will need to tweak the `requiredTime` or the if statement to get the desired effect.

Comment: Even better would be to `setInterval`, otherwise the use has to refresh the page... Otherwise looks nice.

Comment: Yes @JohnDetlefs is correct. Above only checks time on page render. SetInterval would allow it to recheck the current time so to speak. Thanks for the input John!

Answer (score -1):

If it's react, you can follow my code.....

```
<button ...props disabled={specificcase}>Submit</button>
```